# AWS Elastic Load Balancer not responding from Internet connection

Tags: amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

I have created one EC2 instance (as part of the provision of a Tomcat Beanstalk instance). Now I need to configure HTTPS connection to the EC2 instance. As per the Beanstalk documentation, the easiest way is to configure a load balancer that interacts with browsers using HTTPS and that routes traffic to the EC2 instance using HTTP.
So I configured a load balancer under the EC2 management console. After the configuration, I tried to ping the public DNS name of the load balancer or the resolved IP address. The target is reachable but does not produce any response, as shown below:

```
ping 13.54.72.179
PING 13.54.72.179 (13.54.72.179) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
13.54.72.179 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6139ms
```

I carefully checked all the configurations, as per the load balancer configuration and trouble-shooting documentation. All seem to have been configured properly.

- Target group: the target group has the healthy state in monitoring tab.
- VPC: the load balancer availability zone and the EC2 instance are in
  the same VPC zone. Also in the route table, there is an internet
  gateway associated to 0.0.0.0/0 destination.
- load balancer listeners: both HTTP and HTTPS listeners are
  configured. Load balancer is also configured for internet-facing
  connection.
- Security group for load balancer: for inbound traffic, both
  HTTP/HTTPS and TCP protocol are configured, accepting all sources;
  for outbound traffic: all protocols to all destinations are allowed.
- Security group for EC2: for the purpose of testing, we enable all
  traffic for all sources in inbound traffic.

I researched a few forum threads about the "load balancer not responding" topic and checked the configurations they mentioned. However, none of them worked for me.

So I am at loss now. Can someone enlighten me where I might have missed in configuring the load balancer? Or what I need to do for trouble-shooting?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was? I'm having similar troubles.

Comment: I later figured out it was my mistake in configuring the security group attached to the EC2 instance. My experience is that for the issue of connectivity to EC2, it was typically related to security group.

Comment: I realized something similar. I had a security group associated with my ELB that limited ingress. I got that set to 0.0.0.0/0 and now I can get everything.